# How to Use Cache and Keep code DRY in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, dry

I have the following lines of code that are being repeated, not only in many methods of a Controller but also in more than one Controller.

```
$Categories = \Cache::rememberForever('Categories', function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
});
```

Is there any useful way that I can use this, such that the repeated code can be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Repository to access the `Category_Model` model:

```
//REPOSITORY CLASS
class CategoryRepository
{    
    public function getAll()
    {
        return \Cache::rememberForever('Categories', function() {
            return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
        });
    }    
}
```

In the controllers where you need to get the categories, inject the repository from the controller's constructor, and access the repository from the methods:

```
//INJECT THE REPOSITORY IN YOU CONTROLLER'S CONSTRUCTOR
public function __construct( CategoryRepository $catRepo )
{
    $this->catRepo = $catRepo; 
}

public function index()
{
    //get the categories from the repository 
    $categories = $this->catRepo->getAll();  
}
```

This will keep your code **DRY**, as you only need to call `$this->catRepo->getAll();` to get all the categories

Comment: @PankajGarg anywhere you like, could be e.g. app/repositories/ and namespaced as \App\Repositories\

Comment: You can create this class any where inside app directory, just you need to specify proper namespace in the class and use this class using that namespace in the controller.

Comment: @PankajGarg : i've simplified the repository class. You error comes from a namespace problem. Where is your class file placed ? You should set the namespaces accordingly to your folders structure. Or you can use a fully qualified name: looking at your code in the controller's constructor you could specify `\App\Models\Skill\CategoryRepository $catRepo` instead of `CategoryRepository` if the `CategoryRepository` class is in the `Skill` folder